# CSS Containment(contain: layout) doesn't work on Chrome 62

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-contain

I'm trying to use CSS Containment(`contain: layout`), but it doesn't seems to work correctly on Chrome 62.

I want to know a proper way to use `contain: layout` or what is my misunderstanding.

Code is here:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS Containment</title>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="contain: layout; height: 300px; width: 300px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

setTimeout(() => {
    const elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.textContent = 'content';
    container.appendChild(elem);
}, 100);
```

I expect that the #container element is rendered as a layout root after `appendChild(elem)`, but Chrome Dev Tool shows that the root is still the #document.

[image: the screenshot is here.]

On the other hand, `contain: layout size` or `contain: strict` works correctly, which means #container becomes a layout root.

Other browsers don't support CSS Containment yet, so I can't identify it's Chrome-specific or on the spec.

If you have any ideas, please give me a hand.

Comment: Firefox is supporting CSS Containment (except Style, which is not that useful anyway) since version 69.